# Map.Entry next method?

Tags: hashmap, java

I'm looking at the source code for JDK 7 - specifically WeakHashMap.java, where there is extensive use of this:

```
Entry<K,V> p = prev;
Entry<K,V> next = p.next;
```

but next isn't a method defined on Map.Entry (as far as I can see? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)

Where is the call to this method coming from then?

Comment: what method are you talking about?

Comment: next if the next entry linked to the current entry.It's not a method, it's a variable

Comment: @ZouZou yeah, Im far too used to scala and forgot the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WeakHashMap` is not referring to `Map.Entry`, but instead, to its own [internal implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/WeakHashMap.java#WeakHashMap.Entry) of the `Map.Entry` interface, a class named `Entry`.  That class has a field named `next`, which it can access.

Comment: Ah! Explains all, thanks :) (this is what happens what Im not using an IDE >.< )

Answer (score 0):

`next` is not a function.  It is a member variable of a class that is being directly accessed.  Typically you would see this (in OO code)

```
public class Foo  
{  
    String bar;  

    public String getBar()  
    {   
        return this.bar;
    }  
}
```

The `.next` syntax you see is what is commonly referred to as direct member access and is typically frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

It is an inner class inside WeakHashMap, which contains a reference to Entry next:

```
private static class Entry<K,V> extends WeakReference<Object> implements Map.Entry<K,V>{
    V value;
    final int hash;
    Entry<K,V> next;

    Entry(Object key, V value, ReferenceQueue<Object> queue, int hash, Entry<K,V> next) {
    super(key, queue);
    this.value = value;
    this.hash  = hash;
    this.next  = next;

    // omit others...
}
```

Check out the source code at line 682: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/WeakHashMap.java#WeakHashMap.Entry

This is the same thing for HashMap. It has similar inner class:

```
static class Entry<K, V> implements Map.Entry<K, V>
```